# Existence of functions $g, h:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that f = g / h

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a function of bounded variation with $\inf_{x\in[a,b]}f(x)>0$. Show that there are two increasing functions $g, h:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f=g/h$.

They left me an exercise in my course of real analysis and I don't have idea how to start. Somebody could help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $C:= \inf_{x \in [a,b]}f(x) > 0$ and $f$ is of bounded variation, the function
$$F(x):=\log(f(x))$$
is well-defined and also of bounded variation (proof?). We know that any function of bounded variation can be written in the form
$$F(x) = t_1(x) -t_2(x),$$
where $t_1$ and $t_2$ are monotonic increasing function. Thus
$$f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{h(x)}$$
with $g(x) = \exp(t_1(x))$ and $h(x)= \exp(t_2(x))$ and both $g$ and $h$ are increasing functions.

Comment: In this case, the domain of function $F(x)$ is $C$, right? Also, should I prove that $F(x)$ is a function of bounded variation in $C$ or $[a, b]$?

Comment: $F$ is again defined on $[a,b]$ and$F(x) \geq \log(C)$ for all $x \in [a,b]$. We just need that $f(x) \ne 0$ in order to define $F$. However, to get a function of bounded variation, we also need $C>0$.

Comment: the inequality $\log(C)\leq F(x)$ is true because $C\leq f(x)$ for every $x\in[a,b]$ and $C>0$, right? Also, $F(x)$ is a function of bounded variation because is strictly increasing, right?

Comment: After defining the function $ F (x) $ and show that it is a function of bounded variation, then you applied that $ F (X) = t_ {1} (x) -t_ {2} (x) $ with $ t_ {1 } (x) $ and $ t_ {2} (x) $ increasing functions. Then, I can conclude that $ f (x) = g (x) / h (x) $ and not $ F (x) $, right?

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Yes, $f(x) = g(x)/h(x)$. This was a typo, which I have corrected already. Also $F(x)  \ge \log(C)$ is a consequence of $f(x) \ge C$, because $xx \mapsto \log(x)$ is monotonic increasing on $(0,\infty)$. $F(x)$ is not necessarily increasing! Note that \begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^n |\log(f(x_{k+1}))-\log(f(x_k))| &\le \sum_{k=1}^n \int_{f(x_{k})}^{f(x_{k+1})} \frac{1}{x} \, \mathrm{d} x \\ &\le C^{-1} \sum_{k=1}^n |f(x_{k+1}-f(x_k)| \le C^{-1} V(f,[a,b]).\end{align} Thus $F$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: Is there another way to show that $ F (x) $ is a variation function without using integrals? I haven't seen integrals yet....

Comment: Another question. $ F (x) $ would be a increasing function if $ f (x) $ were increasing, right?

Comment: Yes, since $x \mapsto \log(x)$ is also increasing. You can use the mean value theorem (instead of integrals) to deduce the above-mentioned bound.

Comment: Simple and clever argument. +1

Comment: I have an other question. I know that $\log (x)$ is a increasing function and I can apply the mean value theorem to deduce the above, but how does this help me to prove that $F (x)$ is a bounded variation function if $f (x)$ has domain $[a , b]$? Note que $x\in(0,+\infty)$

Comment: I have a question. When you show that inequality by means of integrals, you are saying that $\log x$ is a Lipschitz function, that would imply that $\log x$ is a uniformly continuous function, but $\log x$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,1)$, right?

Comment: Yes, $\log(x)$ is not uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$, but on $(\min f,\max f)$ it is, because $C>0$ and the estimate via integrals (or mean value theorem) implies that $\log(x)$ is Lipschitz. Any continuous differentiable function on a compact set is Lipschitz. (Same Argument.)